# iOS(Objective C) For Retrieving Json Value Statically

Tags: ios, objective-c

While I am wrinting this value statically in my code.
{"id":"2","name":"Test",""}
I want to break it into 3 parts.I have tried the below code but did not succeed.Can someone help me with this to solve?

```
NSString *park_id = @'{"id":2,"parkname":"Test",""}';

NSString *myData = park_id;

NSLog(@"park_id =%@", myData);


NSArray *data_new;

NSArray *data_first = [myData componentsSeparatedByString:@":"][0];

NSArray *data_second = [myData componentsSeparatedByString:@":"][1];

NSLog(@"NewLog = %@", data_second);

NSLog(@"NewLog1 = %@", data_first);

data_new = [data_second[0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@""
                                                      withString:@"\""];
NSLog(@"NewLog2 = %@", data_new);


NSString *message = data_new;


UIAlertController *alert=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *CancelButton=[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

}];
[alert addAction:CancelButton];
```

Comment: What is the result you get from this code and what to you get in fact?

Comment: I just want to break NSString *park_id = @'{"id":2,"parkname":"Test",""}';
this value into 3 parts .But while I am writing this statically in code ,it's returning char(125).

Answer (score 0):

+componentsByString: returns NSArray but at each element of this Array is NSString's Object not NSArray's. So correct it by

```
NSString *data_first = [myData componentsSeparatedByString:@":"][0];

NSString *data_Second = [myData componentsSeparatedByString:@":"][1];
```

after it you do like this,

```
data_new = [data_second stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@""
                                                  withString:@"\""];
NSLog(@"NewLog2 = %@", data_new);
NSString *message = data_new;


UIAlertController *alert=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *CancelButton=[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

}];
[alert addAction:CancelButton];
```